# Gases produced by pyrolysis of cellulose

Tags: home-experiment, combustion, carbohydrates, pyrolysis

I heated cotton in a sealed container (with a small hole) over a natural gas flame. Some gases and smoke were produced. What would they probably be? I can come up with some guesses based on the composition of cellulose: $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{CH4}$ or possibly other hydrocarbons, $\ce{CO}$, $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{H2O}$, however I do not know which of those they are. Obviously, soot ($\ce{C}$) was also formed, due to the visible smoke particles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

During pyrolysis, organic compounds are thermally decomposed in the absence of oxygen. The pyrolysis products are classified into categories based on their physical state of existence: char (solid), bio-oil (liquid) and non-condensable gases (gas). The relative proportions of these three product fractions significantly vary depending upon the process conditions, as is shown in the table below.

$$ \small
\begin{array}{lcc}
\hline
\text{Pyrolosis Technology} & \text{Residence Time} & \text{Heating Rate} & \text{Temperature} & \text{Char} & \text{Bio-Oil} & \text{Gases} \\
\hline
\text{Conventional} & \text{5-30}\ \mathrm{min} & \text{<50} ^\circ \mathrm{C\ min^{-1}} & \text{400-600} ^\circ \mathrm{C} & \text{<35%} & \text{<30%} & \text{<40%}\\
\text{Fast Pyrolysis} & \text{<5}\ \mathrm{s} & \text{~1000} ^\circ \mathrm{C\ s^{-1}} & \text{400-600} ^\circ \mathrm{C} & \text{<25%} & \text{<75%} & \text{<20%}\\
\text{Flash Pyrolosis} & \text{<0.1}\ \mathrm{s} & \text{~1000} ^\circ \mathrm{C\ s^{-1}} & \text{650-900} ^\circ \mathrm{C} & \text{<20%} & \text{<20%} & \text{<70%}^{[1]}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The exact compositions of the products of cellulose pyrolysis at different temperatures can be seen below.

$$ \small
\begin{array}{lcc}
\hline
\text{Products} & \text{Peak Temp,}\ 500 ^\circ \mathrm{C} & \text{Holding Temp,}\ 400 ^\circ \mathrm{C} & \text{Peak Temp,}\ 750 ^\circ \mathrm{C} & \text{Peak Temp,}\ 1000 ^\circ \mathrm{C}\\
\hline
\ce{CO} & \text{0.99%} & \text{0.25%} & \text{15.82%} & \text{22.57%}\\
\ce{CO2} & \text{0.3%} & \text{1.45%} & \text{2.38%} & \text{3.36%}\\
\ce{H2O} & \text{3.55%} & \text{6.49%} & \text{8.72%} & \text{9.22%}\\
\ce{CH4} & \text{0%} & \text{0%} & \text{1.11%} & \text{2.62%}\\
\ce{C2H4} & \text{0%} & \text{0%} & \text{1.05%} & \text{2.18%}\\
\ce{C2H6} & \text{0%} & \text{0%} & \text{0.17%} & \text{0.28%}\\
\ce{C3H6} & \text{0%} & \text{0%} & \text{0.70%} & \text{0.80%}\\
\ce{H2} & \text{0%} & \text{0%} & \text{0.36%} & \text{1.18%}\\
\ce{CH3OH} & \text{0.25%} & \text{0.21%} & \text{1.03%} & \text{0.98%}\\
\ce{CH3CHO} & \text{0.01%} & \text{0.05%} & \text{1.58%} & \text{1.7%}\\
\text{tar} & \text{16.37%} & \text{83.35%} & \text{59.92%} & \text{49.12%}\\
\text{char} & \text{83.63%} & \text{6.17%} & \text{3.32%} & \text{3.91%}\\
\text{other} & \text{0.19%} & \text{0.16%} & \text{2.14%} & \text{1.78%}\\
\text{total} & \text{105.25%} & \text{98.36%} & \text{98.8%} & \text{99.86%}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The holding time for each of these reactions was $30\ \mathrm{s}^{[2]}$. As shown in the table, $\ce{CO}$, $\ce{H2O}$, and $\ce{CO2}$ are the major gaseous products, with $\ce{H2}$ and hydrocarbons being produced in considerably smaller proportion.

---

<sub>$^{[1]}$ [Patwardhan, Pushkaraj Ramchandra, "Understanding the product distribution from biomass fast pyrolysis" (2010). Graduate Theses
and Dissertations. Paper 11767.](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2765&context=etd)

$^{[2]}$ [Hajaligol, M. R.; Howard, J. B.; Longwell, J. P.; Peters, W. A. Product Compositions and Kinetics for Rapid Pyrolysis of Cellulose. Industrial & Engineering Chemistry Process Design and Development Ind. Eng. Chem. Proc. Des. Dev. 1982, 21, 457–465.](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/i200018a019)</sub>

Comment: Impressive. Do you make the tables by hand or is there some tool for making them?

Comment: @CopperKettle  I did have to enter the data manually, but the formatting was taken from [this meta post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/310/15410). Digging around the sandboxes can yield some really neat $\LaTeX$ tools :)

Comment: As usual, the most interesting part (nearly everything that gives color and smell) is also the hardest to analyze, so it is just swept under the rug and called "tar".

Comment: @IvanNeretin On page 30 of the [first source](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2765&context=etd), there is a detailed analysis of exactly what this tar is. This question isn't about tar though, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: Wow. Now that's very impressive indeed.

Comment: This is really nice, with the graphs and all. Thanks (and the bounty goes to you, when I can award it.)