# What would happen if you burned paper with a laser, in a vacuum?

Tags: combustion, carbohydrates

If you hit a piece of paper with a powerful laser inside a vacuum, what would happen? It sounds like it should not "burn" and have a flame spread over the paper, as there is, of course, no oxygen.

Would it perhaps turn the paper into a thin sheet of charcoal where the laser makes contact? If so, perhaps one could make a cnc-type machine within a vacuum chamber that automatically cuts out [stencils.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYtzu.png)

Comment: One doesn't need vacuum to cut paper with laser. It's been about a decade since affordable laser paper cutting machines appeared on the market, I remember there was a little spike of interest in that area, but then 3D printing took the mind of the masses.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49827/gases-produced-by-pyrolysis-of-cellulose